# How to Use Lucene TestUtil for random Unicode String Generation

Tags: java, unit-testing, lucene

I'm working on some code for generating random Unicode strings. I tried to use Lucene Test Utils My code to generate Random Unicode Strings is as follows

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        Random random = new Random();
        final String s = TestUtil.randomUnicodeString(random, 12);
        //final String s = TestUtil.randomUnicodeString(random);Tried both
        final byte[] utf8 = new byte[s.length() * UnicodeUtil.MAX_UTF8_BYTES_PER_CHAR];
        final int utf8Len = UnicodeUtil.UTF16toUTF8(s, 0, s.length(), utf8);
        if(utf8Len !=8)
        {
            System.out.println("$$$$");
        }
    }
```

So  i checked the implemention for randomUnicodeString in lucene code for Lucene version  6.2.0

```
public static String randomUnicodeString(Random r, int maxLength) {
final int end = nextInt(r, 0, maxLength);
if (end == 0) {
  // allow 0 length
  return "";
}
final char[] buffer = new char[end];
randomFixedLengthUnicodeString(r, buffer, 0, buffer.length);
return new String(buffer, 0, end);
```

}

and subsequent code for randomFixedLengthUnicodeString is

```
 public static void randomFixedLengthUnicodeString(Random random, char[] chars, int offset, int length) {
int i = offset;
final int end = offset + length;
while(i < end) {
  final int t = random.nextInt(5);
  if (0 == t && i < length - 1) {
    // Make a surrogate pair
    // High surrogate
    chars[i++] = (char) nextInt(random, 0xd800, 0xdbff);
    // Low surrogate
    chars[i++] = (char) nextInt(random, 0xdc00, 0xdfff);
  } else if (t <= 1) {
    chars[i++] = (char) random.nextInt(0x80);
  } else if (2 == t) {
    chars[i++] = (char) nextInt(random, 0x80, 0x7ff);
  } else if (3 == t) {
    chars[i++] = (char) nextInt(random, 0x800, 0xd7ff);
  } else if (4 == t) {
    chars[i++] = (char) nextInt(random, 0xe000, 0xffff);
  }
}
```

}

so what could be the reason for the Exception that i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/carrotsearch/randomizedtesting/generators/RandomInts
at org.apache.lucene.util.TestUtil.nextInt(TestUtil.java:433)
at org.apache.lucene.util.TestUtil.randomUnicodeString(TestUtil.java:505)
at luceneLab.lab.main(lab.java:33)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.generators.RandomInts
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 3 more
```

am i passing the wrong arguments for the method to generate Random String or some interdependencies i am missing ?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Exception says, you are missing com/carrotsearch/randomizedtesting/generators/RandomInts in your project. Looks like TestUtil uses [com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting](https://labs.carrotsearch.com/randomizedtesting.html), so you'll need to add it as a dependency to your project.